# Getting error while importing a new module to Vtiger 6.0.0Beta

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

I have created a module just to print a message using the following tutorial:

http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/create-simple-module-vtiger-crm

I changed the contents of language file into array format. It was able to import the module and was working fine in Vtiger 5.4.0. But when I tried to install it in Vtiger 6.0.0Beta, it is raising the error:

"Invalid File provided for module import! Try Again."

Anybody having the same issue resolved?

Comment: Please post your code at the time of asking question. So we can reply for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't what code you are using. So Use this code to create a new Module. Hope this might help you.

```
<?php
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
$myExtensionModule = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('MyExtension');
if ($myExtensionModule) {
Vtiger_Utils::Log("Module already exits.");
} else {
$myExtensionModule = new Vtiger_Module();
$myExtensionModule->name = 'MyExtension';
$myExtensionModule->label= 'My Extension';
$myExtensionModule->parent='Tools';
$myExtensionModule->save();
}
?>
```

And Create one File at place vtigercrm/modules/MyExtension/MyExtension.php

Use the code Below

```
<?php
/** License Text Here **/
class MyExtension {
/**
 * Invoked when special actions are performed on the module.
 * @param String Module name
 * @param String Event Type (module.postinstall, module.disabled, module.enabled, module.preuninstall)
 */
function vtlib_handler($modulename, $event_type) {
    if($event_type == 'module.postinstall') {
        // TODO Handle post installation actions
    } else if($event_type == 'module.disabled') {
        // TODO Handle actions when this module is disabled.
    } else if($event_type == 'module.enabled') {
        // TODO Handle actions when this module is enabled.
    } else if($event_type == 'module.preuninstall') {
        // TODO Handle actions when this module is about to be deleted.
    } else if($event_type == 'module.preupdate') {
        // TODO Handle actions before this module is updated.
    } else if($event_type == 'module.postupdate') {
        // TODO Handle actions after this module is updated.
    }
}
}
?>
```

Add Code here vtigercrm/modules/MyExtension/language/en_us.lang.php

```
<?php
/** License Text Here **/
$mod_strings = array(
'My Extension'=> 'My Extension'
);
```

vtigercrm/vtiger6/modules/MyExtension/views/List.php

```
<?php
/** License Text Here **/
class MyExtension_List_View extends Vtiger_Index_View {

public function process(Vtiger_Request $request) {
    $viewer = $this->getViewer($request);
    $viewer->view('Index.tpl', $request->getModule());
}
}
?>
```

vtigercrm/vtiger6/layouts/default/modules/MyExtension/IndexViewPreProcess.tpl

```
{include file="Header.tpl"|vtemplate_path:$MODULE}
{include file="BasicHeader.tpl"|vtemplate_path:$MODULE}
<div class="bodyContents">
<div class="mainContainer row-fluid">
    <div class="contentsDiv span12">
```

vtigercrm/vtiger6/layouts/default/modules/MyExtension/Index.tpl

```
<h2>{$MODULE} module <small>working now.</small></h2>
```

vtigercrm/vtiger6/languages/en_us/MyExtension.php

```
<?php
/** License Text Here **/
$languageStrings = array(  
'My Extension' => 'My Extension'
);
```